# MySQL: How to copy data (tables) from database to another database with different user

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for a query to copy data from one database/table to another database/table with different user credentials?

Comment: If the same user doesnt have read from source and write to destination then you will have to dump the data from the source and load it to destination as different usres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a query, unless your user has rights on both schemas.

Try this `mysqldump -u user dbname.tablename | mysql -u user2 dbname`

Comment: I think I should update my question, I want to move the DB and Yeah this is true for a single table, what if I want to move DB itself?

Comment: To move the DB, simply remove `.tablename`

Comment: Bravo it works, thanks a ton, wish I had known this earlier nonetheless it's good to know. Thanks @burhan-khalid

Answer (score 2):

To copy data from one table to another :

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT COL1, COL4, COL7 FROM TABLE1
```

To copy data from one database to another :

```
 USE `old_database`;

 INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)

 SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column3`, `old_table`.`column5`

 FROM `old_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no straight way to copy any database to another database with different users.

Only way I could successfully complete this task is to write a script to take the dump and run it over another database.

Comment: Well I thought I never had a solution to this question and hence posted this answer, but as soon as I did, I got the answer from @burhan-khalid - see the accepted answer.